# validates_uniqueness_of by two fields

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the model:

```
class Action
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :assignment_date, type: Date
  ...

  index(
    [
      [ :name, Mongo::ASCENDING ],
      [ :assignment_date, Mongo::ASCENDING ]
      ], 
      unique: true
  )

  validates_uniqueness_of [ :name, :assignment_date ]
```

But when I'm trying to insert the 2 different document with the same name, but different assigned_date I get the error:

```
Mongoid::Errors::Validations - Validation failed - Name is already taken, Assignment date is already taken.:
```

I have tryed both versions:

```
  validates_uniqueness_of [ :name, :assignment_date ]
```

and

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :assignment_date
```

If I'll comment this line all works fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mongoid:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :assignment_date
```

From the docs: Note that for embedded documents, this will only check that the field is unique within the context of the parent document, not the entire database.

http://mongoid.org/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 14):

Accoring to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness) rails guide you can do the following:

```
validates :assignment_date, :uniqueness => { :scope => :name }
```

Comment: Maybe not rails, but you're using ActiveModel which is being used by rails, hence the validations are kinda the same. But thanks for the downvote!